# Heroku, accesing laravel storage folder

Tags: laravel, heroku

When the button clicked, it is supposed to open a file of "resume.pdf" in a blank page. It works fine with localhost, but when it is executed on heroku, it doesn't go through well. I think the path is wrong but I have no idea which path should be.

composer.json

```
"post-install-cmd": [
  "php artisan clear-compiled",
  "php artisan optimize",
  "chmod -R 775 public/",
  "chmod -R 775 storage/"
],
```

index.php

```
<a class="btn btn-xl btn-outline-light" href="storage/resume.pdf" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o mr-2"></i>
    View Resume!
</a>
```

[Accessed in Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEk6r.png)

[Accessed on Herokuapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL89g.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this answer has two parts.

The first is that `storage` isn't publicly accessible by default. [Per the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#the-public-disk):

> To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to  storage/app/public. This convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.

(You probably did this locally once, but forgot. Or, your local server is running out of the app's main folder instead of the `public` subfolder.)

**BUT...**

On Heroku, the filesystem is ephemeral. **It is not permanent.** [Files you store on the instance can go away at *any time*.](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) If you do a new deploy, or if you scale up/down, or if Heroku needs to restart/replace an instance, alllllll the files your users have uploaded to `storage` are **wiped out**.

Instead, you'll want to store user uploads somewhere like Amazon S3, which Laravel makes easy. Once you've configured your S3 keys, you can just do stuff like `Storage::disk('s3')` to work with S3 instead of the local, soon-to-be-erased disk.

Comment: Of course, if you're just putting your *own* files in `storage` **and** checking them into version control so they're deployed with the app, consider putting them in `public` instead for ease of use. Saves you a symlink.

Comment: well, I already created the symbolic link "/storage/resume.pdf"  to /public, but it does not still work. So, I just put the pdf file to /public as you told me. It works fine now. But, not sure for the solution to accessing /storage folder