# How to host Laravel/React web application on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, laravel, heroku, free

Not sure on which Stack subforum to ask so feel free to correct me.

Question: Can you host Laravel web app with React frontend on Heroku for free? I read something, somewhere, long ago that it can. If any one knows and if also knows any good tutorials/articles for said Laravel+React web app calamity, that would be great.

Ps: I got github repo for said app, so if that helps ...

Mucho kudos in advance.

**Edit1:**

I figured it out by reading [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel?fbclid=IwAR0UO39DrIe--4yZLUZCOGDmhkfTCNSm52fKp4Elh3IQ0iaaOSjPqgQywKY) and by watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=639Pe0PpVLQ&fbclid=IwAR2RaSr7C7ZC4WIfR0rvW31sBnCyk27x5xtVXMl_uN7pTdBERA3xAtadnd4)

Now i have different problem. Some font files for the app are accessed from public folder. Heroku than says cors not allowed.
I tried creating middleware([example](https://medium.com/@KrishaWeb/cross-origin-request-blocked-error-in-laravel-5-5-a733232795e4)), i also tried with some packages, not sure if it's Heroku or what, but my attempts of tackling this ended to no avail.

What would be my next vector of approach to this problem?

**Edit2:**
An url to my [web app](http://pizzzas.herokuapp.com/). My web app is using this space [image: here].

This is how it would look like when i seed Heroku: [image: image from my local machine]
an image from my local machine.

**Edit3:**
An image of data send by ajax call:

[image: ajax call]

it sends data of user, but not of articles, like they're not seeded at all...

**Edit4:**
I am surprised? now. I sincerily don't know what i have done, but cors errors have disappeared ... Still seeding still doesn't work ..

**Edit5:**

Cors error persist still, but only when user get logged in. Don't why is this happening, it's peculiar ... Anyhow, besides these cors errors, images uploaded to storage folder, even after creating symlink on Heroku, don't persist. It must be like it is explained in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082602/heroku-accesing-laravel-storage-folder). Still, all main functionalities work, that's something right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

You can do it by setting the Laravel preset to react (it comes with Vue by default) with:

`$ php artisan preset react`

This installs all the required dependencies and also creates a dummy Example in your resources directory.

Now you can build the js by compiling your assets with

`npm run prod`

This will generate your app.js file with all you need to include React components in your views. You can push it to heroku as usual.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Already did that, thanks. See edit for different problem now.

Comment: Do you have any 'out-of-react' requests in your project? for example some jquery or plain js ajax calls. Do they work?

Comment: Yes, they are communicating with db which btw isn't seeded currently. What's that got to do with cors? Cors is just saying stuff about some font files which are in public folder?

Comment: How are they communicating with db? Do you mean php controllers and so? This has nothing to do with react or CORS issues. Maybe you could add your directory structure (to show those files in the public folder) and the specific error you get to your question.

Comment: By making ajax request to given routes with controller methods in mind i.e. `/articles` returns list of articles. I'll post url to it in post edit.

Comment: I meant the CORS error. Because if you are doing ajax calls directly and you don't get the CORS error in them, it means you have this header well configured, and has nothing to do with react. Anyway the font files should be in the public folder since the browser needs to access them.